# Clicking on the synonym tag throws error page about cookies (with custom question lists enabled)

Tags: bug, status-completed, tag-synonyms, cookies, custom-question-lists

In the [Tag Synonyms](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms?tab=synonym&filter=all) page, if I clicked on any of the tag under the Synonym section, it throws the following error page. For example: [duplicates](/questions/tagged/duplicates).

The error message in plain text as:

> The page isn’t redirecting properly
>
> An error occurred during a connection to meta.stackexchange.com.
>
> This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to accept cookies.

Is this a known issue or a error?

The error page:

> [image: Error page]

Comment: I noticed this too, but it goes away in Incognito.

Comment: Also reproduceable in mobile chrome.

Comment: No repro, this is most likely a bug in the new new new nav aka custom question lists. @MEE you also got it enabled, right? :)

Comment: Reproduced with custom question lists enabled. Disabled it and after caching caught up, redirects started working fine.

Comment: @ShadowWizard yes I enabled custom question lists. This seems to be the cause of the error, as has been noted on Meta Stack Overflow too.

Comment: **Issue also reported on Meta Stack Overflow: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/380000/when-logged-in-pages-from-tags-that-are-now-synonyms-do-not-render**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This embarrassing bug will be fixed in the next build.

This was only affecting CQL-enabled users because the non-CQL code has a different generator.

[image: screenshot showing that the function producing the URL was straight-up ignoring the tag parameter.]

Comment: Would you also reply on the [MSO report](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/380000/when-logged-in-pages-from-tags-that-are-now-synonyms-do-not-render) and mark it completed? Thanks! :)